# Different structures on the same ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\times,0,1)$ be an unitary ring. I need to find two new operations such that $(R,+_1,\times _1,1)$ is also a ring with the new zero element the $1$ of the first ring. I've thought of the new sum as:

$$a+_1b:=a+b-1$$

so that we have:

$$a+_1 1= a+1-1=a$$

But I don't see how to conclude, any idea?

Comment: Exchanging + und * does not work: additively a group, multiplicatively a monoid.

Comment: @Wuestenfux thanks in fact that's not what I did but whatever

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take a bijection $\phi:R\rightarrow R$.
Since $(R,+,0)$ forms an abelian group, $R$ forms an abelian group under the operation
$$s\oplus t := \phi^{-1}(\phi(s)+\phi(t)),\quad s,t\in R,$$
where $e=\phi^{-1}(0)$ is the zero element.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see how this helps me, in my exercise $R$ is a generic ring...

Comment: Generic ring or not. I don't care.

Comment: Okay I got it: you used the blackboardmath, as like everybody uses to specifically indicate real numbers, for the generic ring $R$ for... reasons I guess. So I have to take a bijection for which $1=\phi ^{-1} (0)$ but then what do I do for multiplication?

Comment: My example in mind was an open interval $(a,b)$ and a bijection $\phi:(a,b)\rightarrow{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really cannot see your point

Comment: Giving an interval a group structure. But it works in general terms...

Comment: Okay, fine. But my problem is with multiplication which I don't see how to define.

Comment: Similar to addition.